# Posting photo to facebook works fine for $_FILES[]["tmp_name"] but not a local filepath?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm having trouble using the facebook api to post a photo to a page's wall. If I upload the file via php and use $_FILES[]["tmp_name"] as my $filelocation it works fine. However if I change $filelocation to a local filepath ( /tmp/1351750505-24d.jpg ) it doesn't work.

I've given my /tmp dir 777 and made sure my file is 777 as well to eliminate any permission issues. I've also used multiple files to make sure its not just an issue with one file.

The only other thought I have is that this could be a random setting in php.ini, but I didn't see anything glaring at me.

Error log:

```
[Thu Nov 01 06:52:13 2012] [error] [client 66.x.x.x] {"error":{"message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}, referer: http://origin.example.com/adder/index.php
[Thu Nov 01 06:52:13 2012] [error] [client 66.x.x.x] $filelocation = /tmp/1351752730-24e.jpg, referer: http://origin.example.com/adder/index.php




[ec2-user@ip-10-x-x-x adder]$ ll /tmp/1351750505-24d.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 331 Nov  1 06:15 /tmp/1351750505-24d.jpg


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$post_id = "";

try
{
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/photos", 'POST',
                                array(
                                    'source' => '@' . $filelocation,
                                    'message' => $name
                                 ));
    error_log("\$filelocation = " . $filelocation);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
    $result = $e->getResult();
    error_log(json_encode($result));
    $post_id["id"] = "FAIL!";
    error_log("\$filelocation = " . $filelocation);

}
```

Comment: I think instead of local path if you give complete url to that image it would work. It works with javascript sdk not sure about php. Try using **"url"** parameter instead of **"source"** and give complete url path starting with https://...

Comment: Thanks, using url instead of source works and I can use that as a workaround to get through my backlog. If anyone knows how to resolve my source problem, or has some helpful troubleshooting steps I may have missed, please let me know.

Comment: If you look at the `source` field description in the [Graph API photo documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) it should be a "**string representing a valid URL**". Facebook can't scrape a local path on your server.

Answer (score 0):

When I set `$filelocation` to `/tmp/somefile.jpg` it posts the local path/file fine.  I notice one difference between your code and my code: I include the page access token in the POST call:

```
$local_path = '/tmp/water96x96.jpg';

$args = array(
  'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
  'message' => 'Testing photo upload via SDK!',
  'source' => '@'.$local_path,
);

$post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

To get the page access token, I do:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token');
```

with a logged in user who is an admin of the page with `manage_pages` permission.